# Lebesgue integral is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Problem: Let F be a closed set in $\Bbb R$ with finite measure complement, and let $\delta(x)$ denote the distance from x to F. Show that $I(x)=\int_{\Bbb R} \dfrac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2} dy=\infty$ for each $x\notin F$.

Attempts:

It is easy to check that $|\delta(x)-\delta(y)|\le |x-y|$ for any $x,y\in\Bbb R$. Then $\delta(y)-\delta(x)\ge -|y-x|$ and hence $I(x)=\int_{F^c} \dfrac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2} dy\ge -\int_{F^c}\dfrac1{|x-y|}dy.$

Let $A_n=\{y\in F^c: |x-y|\le n\} $, then $A_n\to F^c$ as $n\to\infty$

$I(x)=\int_{F^c} \dfrac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2} dy\ge \int_{F_+^c} \dfrac{|\delta(y)-\delta(x)|}{|x-y|^2} dy-\int_{F_-^c} \dfrac{|\delta(y)-\delta(x)|}{|x-y|^2} dy$, where $F_+^c=\{y\in F^c: \delta(y)\gt \delta(x)\}$ and vice versa. The second part of the intergrand is $\ge -\dfrac1{|x-y|}$, and $\int_{{A_n}_+} \dfrac{|\delta(y)-\delta(x)|}{|x-y|^2} dy\ge \int_{{A_n}_+} \dfrac{|\delta(y)-\delta(x)|}{n^2} dy$.

Let $B_n=\{y\in F^c: \dfrac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}\le n \}$, then $B_n\to F^c$ as $n\to\infty$, and $\int_{B_n} \dfrac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}dy\le \int_{B_n}n dy=m(B_n)n\to m(F^c)n\to \infty$

Is any of those valid? How might I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a point $x\in F^c$. As $F$ is closed, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_{2\varepsilon}(x)\subseteq F^c$. However, then we have $$I(x)\geq \int_{\vert x-y\vert <\varepsilon} \frac{\varepsilon}{\vert x-y\vert^2}dy =\varepsilon \int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon \frac{1}{s^2}ds =\infty.$$

Comment: Where does the epsilon in the numerator come from? Is it continuity?

Comment: That is because $B_{2\varepsilon}(x)\subseteq F^c$, so the distance to $F$ is at least $\varepsilon$ on $B_\varepsilon(x)$. If you have any question, just let me know.

Comment: I have just to make sure that I get a lower bound for $\delta$ on my domain of integration and this was the easiest I could come up with.